# Are “close as duplicate” votes being timed out too quickly?

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close, duplicate-questions

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1929867/using-xname-or-name-in-wpf) (now closed) is clearly a duplicate, the asker confirms it is a duplicate in a comment and at 5 people has mark the duplicate comment as helpful.   The top voted answer is also a link only answer pointing to an answer on the “master” question.

It has had a few close as duplicate votes that have timed out.

**Is the system working as intended, if not what needs changing?**

---

Does the “timed out after n views” need to be changed to “timed out after n views by users that often vote to close”?

Comment: I've just voted to close :)

Comment: Note that the comment referenced is over 4 years old and only got 5 upvotes in that time.

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy, I expect that as the question has not been active for a long time, most views are coming from Google, rather than users that are likely to up vote the comment.

Comment: Perhaps, "timed out after n views by users that **can** vote to close".