# Autoflag after N expired close votes

Tags: feature-request, vote-to-close, 10k-tools

So I read [Are “close as duplicate” votes being timed out too quickly?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/221760/223030), and it got me thinking about close vote expiry. Under the current system, your close vote is *not* refunded if it expires (that is, you may not vote again on that question). There's [a feature request to change that](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/99333/223030), but that's not the point here.

Point is, if a question repeatedly attracts lonely close votes which expire, it may be a close-worthy question largely slipping through the net. What I'm proposing is an automated 10k-visible flag on questions that have a large number of close votes expire (say `>= 6`). This would raise the question to 10k and moderator attention, allowing it to attract the necessary number of votes to actually be closed.

The problem of questions that *aren't* close-worthy repeatedly triggering the flag would be solved entirely by making it one-time-only - if the 10k brigade doesn't think the question is worth being closed, clearly it isn't.